# SciFi short on YouTube about a spacecraft is travelling through space with only AI

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence, short-film

A spacecraft is travelling through space with only AI. As the story moves forward it is revealed that all the scientists onboard the craft have died a long time ago, and now the AI is evolving to become a conscious being. If I remember correctly, the craft is destroyed in the end of the short movie.

I also somehow remember that the AI regarded one of the scientists as a mother figure to it, and also that as the scientist's life was coming to an end, she asked the AI whether it wanted to "not exist", to be turned off, but the AI decided to stay online.

Can't find this SciFi short on YouTube any longer.

Comment: Welcome to the site. In roughly what year did you watch this?

Comment: I guess the short had been on YouTube for some time already when I first saw it, and that was within a year, a year and a half ago.

Comment: Have you checked on the DUST sci-fi YouTube channel? Lots of sci-fi shirts on there. Just a a suggestion.

Comment: Yes, went that through first thing, no luck there. :(